# Programmatically sending keys to a textbox does not update its binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox, keyboard

I am using a ThirdParty keyboard control (DotNetBar from DevComponents, link [here](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/TouchKeyboardControl.aspx)) within a WPF desktop application to enter text within a TextBox control. The application is developped on Windows 8 and .NET 4.5.

**NOTE:** The Windows Tablet Tip was tried, but it has many limitations which makes it difficult to use.

The keyboard being a WindowsForms control, it is put within a WindowsFormsHost. 
Since the WindowsForms SendKeys method used by this keyboard will not work well in WPF (as mentionned in many articles on SO), I am programmatically sending the keys to the textbox using the InputManager, like so:

```
    private void _keyboardControl_SendingKey(object sender, KeyboardKeyCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // to prevent SendKeys to happen.
        e.Cancel = true;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Key))
        {
            return;
        }

        // A special key is a key like "Enter", "Backspace", "Left arrow", ...
        if (IsSpecialKey(e.Key))
        {
            var keyEventArgs = new KeyEventArgs(
               System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
                System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource,
               0,
               GetKeyValueFromStringCode(e.Key)) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent };
            InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(keyEventArgs);
        }
        // "Normal" keys, like a, b, C, (, 1, ....
        else
        {
           var textCompositionEventArgs = new TextCompositionEventArgs(
           System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
            new TextComposition(InputManager.Current,
                System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.FocusedElement,
                e.Key)) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.TextInputEvent };

            InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(textCompositionEventArgs);
        }
    }
```

This effectively puts the right keys into the target WPF textbox which has the focus prior to showing the ThirdParty keyboard.
The textbox Text property has binding to a ViewModel property. The issue is that the updates made to the textbox are not being propagated through the binding when keys are entered programmatically.
If I use my own physical keyboard to type within the same textbox instead, the binding is correctly updated.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. It took a while to get here, it would be too bad if what I'm trying is not possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value for *Text DP of TextBox* by default is `LostFocus`. So source of binding won't be updated until lost focus fired on textBox.

You need to set it to `PropertyChanged`, so that whenever Text property changes, it gets updated to source binding.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PropertyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Rohit for answering this fast. Much appreciated! 
I guess when typing using the physical keyboard, the focus is lost but the text is still being sent to the textbox. I am explicitly doing a "Focusable=fasle;" in my WindowsFormsHost so that Keyboard.FocusedElement and Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource send the keys in my TextBox. This wouldn't work otherwise and would rather not have to reference my TextBox control explicitly.